# How to copy whole file from command line without changing destination creation time

Tags: linux, cp

I want to copy one file's content to another file without replacing the destination file. Because I need to retain the destination file's creation time.

It is fine if its modification time gets changed.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking for is impossible using most filesystems available on GNU/Linux systems. This is due to the fact that filesystems will take modification times and creation times to be the same thing.

What you can do, though, is to first save timestamp(s) of the file you're going to replace, then apply timestamp(s) afterwards again. This will accomplish nearly what you'd like to see to happen ie. creation times which are equal to modification times, would be saved over the content replacement operation.

For the following example to work you need GNU coreutils (usually available and installed on any GNU/Linux distribution) stat(1).

```
#!/bin/sh

s=`stat --format="%y" "$2"`
cp "$1" "$2"
touch --date="$s" --time=mtime "$2"
```

Put that in a file somewhere, e.g. `/usr/local/bin/specialcp`.

Just to give an example regarding some of the other answers, see what happens when you replace file contents using `>`:

```
user@host:~/work/j$ touch --date="Sun, 29 Feb 2004 16:21:42 -0800" j
user@host:~/work/j$ stat j
  File: `j'
  Size: 0               Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: 807h/2055d      Inode: 528815      Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: ( 1001/     user)   Gid: ( 1001/     user)
Access: 2004-03-01 02:21:42.000000000 +0200
Modify: 2004-03-01 02:21:42.000000000 +0200
Change: 2014-04-26 12:28:51.257855694 +0300
 Birth: -
user@host:~/work/j$ cat /etc/profile > j
user@host:~/work/j$ stat j
  File: `j'
  Size: 665             Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 807h/2055d      Inode: 528815      Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: ( 1001/     user)   Gid: ( 1001/     user)
Access: 2004-03-01 02:21:42.000000000 +0200
Modify: 2014-04-26 12:28:58.814855890 +0300
Change: 2014-04-26 12:28:58.814855890 +0300
 Birth: -
```

Modification time has been updated. But, with stat(1) you can save the modification time, do your content replacement/cp(1)/whatever, and then replace the timestamp(s) later with touch(1).

And the same thing happens when using `rsync` as suggested in one of the other answers:

```
user@host:~/work/j$ touch --date="Sun, 29 Feb 2004 16:21:42 -0800" j
user@host:~/work/j$ stat j
  File: `j'
  Size: 0               Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: 807h/2055d      Inode: 528815      Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: ( 1001/     user)   Gid: ( 1001/     user)
Access: 2004-03-01 02:21:42.000000000 +0200
Modify: 2004-03-01 02:21:42.000000000 +0200
Change: 2014-04-26 12:35:11.515865554 +0300
 Birth: -
user@host:~/work/j$ rsync -a /etc/profile j
user@host:~/work/j$ stat j
  File: `j'
  Size: 665             Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 807h/2055d      Inode: 530708      Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: ( 1001/     user)   Gid: ( 1001/     user)
Access: 2014-04-26 12:35:19.198865753 +0300
Modify: 2014-02-08 08:59:51.000000000 +0200
Change: 2014-04-26 12:35:19.198865753 +0300
 Birth: -
```

Answer (score 3):

Do not use `cp` then. Use

```
cat file.xxx > alreadyexistingFile.yyy
```

This will replace the file contents, changing the modification time but not the creation time.

Comment: Actually you should use `>`, because you want the file contents replaced. Please check your formatting too -- code requires backticks and indent by 4 spaces. You can [edit] your post anytime and use the preview window below.

Comment: 10x for the comment :-)

Comment: Are you sure this works? In most systems `(struct stat *)->st_ctime` equals to the file change time, not the file creation time as one might suspect, and changes every time file contents change, regardless of the way contents change as this is something done by filesystem. For example most commonly used filesystems in GNU/Linux systems tend to behave like this.

Comment: @SamiLaine Good point. I guess you'd need to manually copy the timestamps then?

Answer (score 3):

Most filesystems do not track file creation time. ctime records the time of the last change, not creation.  There is also atime (time of last access) and mtime (time of last modification).

ctime can't really be controlled, but mtime can.  Note that mtime is what is listed when you do `ls -l`. One way to change the mtime is:

```
touch -m -t 201402011030 filename
```

Comment: But this is just plain wrong. The original question was about preserving the *destination* file modification time and what this does is that it copies the modification time of the *source* file to the modification time of destination file.

Comment: Youre completely correct.  My original response was wrong, I've updated it.